# C# Naudio Mp3 Play Button

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio

I'm trying over a few days and can't make a simple Play button over C# using NAudio. It works, but when I hit the button the sound doesn't come out. Tried to put the mp3 file on the project folder and nothing happens.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }
        private WaveOut waveOut;
        private Mp3FileReader reader;



    private void Button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   reader = new Mp3FileReader("c:\\tng\\tng.mp3");
   waveOut = new WaveOut(); 
   waveOut.Init(reader); 
   waveOut.Play();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift  your content quality up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I didn't really run just guess) Try this?

```
   reader = new Mp3FileReader("c:\\tng\\tng.mp3");
   waveOut = new WaveOut(); 
   waveOut.Init(reader); 
   waveOut.Play();
   //add this line
   Thread.Sleep(600000);
```